# 2D arraylist with one element into 1D arraylist in java

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist

If I know that my `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` will only contain one element (one list inside a list) how can I transform it into a 1D ArrayList. Such that from `[["A","B"]]` I get `["A","B"]`?

Comment: `listOfLists.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());` - Works even if there are mutliple lists. [Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/MdFbNA)

Comment: Your 2D list contains 1D list which means you already have *some* 1D list (which is inside). Why would you want to convert your 2D list into 1D? Just `2dList.get(indexOf1DList)`.

Comment: @Pshemo because I don't want to create a new variable

Comment: @Timmy333 why? What is the disadvantage you which you want to avoid? Anyway you can't change type of variable, so you can't change `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> variable` into `ArrayList<String> variable` so you don't have many options (maybe raw types but that would be medicine which is worse than a disease - see: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321))

Comment: Also I never suggested creating new variable. You can always use `2dList.get(indexOf1DList)` in all places directly instead of storing it in variable.

Comment: Ohh. I get you know, one more complication is that I also have to remove the first string. Such that from `[["A","B","C"]]` I want `["B","C"]`, is it possible to do `2dList.get(0).remove(0)` ?

Comment: Yes. `2dList.get(0)` should return inner list which holds `["A","B","C"]` so you can call on it `remove(0)` to remove `"A"`.

Answer (score 1):

If we run under Java 8+, we will be able to use the [`java.stream` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) to solve the problem:

```
listOfLists.stream() // transform the list into a stream, i.e. each element in 
                     // the list (in our case: List<String>) will appear in the 
                     // Stream.

    .flatMap(List::stream) // flatten the stream: for each element in the stream 
                           // (List<String> in our case), stream those entries 
                           // (Strings), construct a new stream over all entries 
                           // (Strings) of all List<String>s in the stream

    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // returns all `String`s in a new List<String>
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/MdFbNA)

Comment: I tried to test this using this code: `ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2","3"));
        ArrayList<ArrayList> b = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(a));
        System.out.println(b);
        b.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(b);` but it doesn't seem to be working, I get `[["1","2","3"]]` both times

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/MdFbNA)? We have to assign the result of the streaming operations to a variable: `List<String> result = listOfList.stream()...`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to get the first element with the `get` method.
Then you put it in a new variable that you call `oneD` for example.